# Adding a TextView dynamically in a fragment, in a ScrollView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I know that there were a lot of questions like this one, but I haven't been able to find the answer I'm looking for...

I'd like to dynamically create some `TextView` in an already existing `ScrollView`. I've done something that I thought would have been okay, but the app stops when it comes to this fragment?

I can't put the whole project because the files are numerous, but here are the concerned `.java` and `.xml`:

NotesPageFragment.java

```
package com.a3m.Controllers.Fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.a3m.Controllers.ui.Controler;
import com.a3m.Controllers.core.Task;
import com.a3m.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class NotesPageFragment extends Fragment {

    private Controler controler;
    private ScrollView mScrollView;

    public static NotesPageFragment newInstance() {

        return(new NotesPageFragment());
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notes_page, container, false);
        this.controler = Controler.getInstance();
        this.mScrollView = v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_page_notes_scrollview);
        //addNotes(notes,getAllTasks());
        addNotes(v, getAllTasks());
        return v;
    }

    public ArrayList<Task> getAllTasks()
    {
       /*
       ** ici le code qui se connecte à la bdd et retourne toutes les tasks disponibles
        */


        ArrayList<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

        ArrayList<String> n =new ArrayList<>();
        n.add("detail1");
        n.add("detail2");
        n.add("detail3");
        Task t1=new Task(0,0,null,"t1",0,0,null,0,null,null,n,null);
        Task t2=new Task(0,0,null,"t2",0,0,null,0,null,null,n,null);
        Task t3=new Task(0,0,null,"t3",0,0,null,0,null,null,n,null);
        Task t4=new Task(0,0,null,"t4",0,0,null,0,null,null,n,null);
        Task t5=new Task(0,0,null,"t5",0,0,null,0,null,null,n,null);
        Task t6=new Task(0,0,null,"t6",0,0,null,0,null,null,n,null);
        Task t7=new Task(0,0,null,"t7",0,0,null,0,null,null,n,null);

        tasks.add(t1);
        tasks.add(t2);
        tasks.add(t3);
        tasks.add(t4);
        tasks.add(t5);
        tasks.add(t6);
        tasks.add(t7);
        return tasks;
    }

    public void addNotes(View view, ArrayList<Task> tasks) {
        Iterator<Task> itr_tasks = tasks.iterator();
        Task task;
        String taskNote;
        while(itr_tasks.hasNext()) {
            taskNote = "";
            task = itr_tasks.next();
            taskNote += task.getName();
            Iterator<String> itr_notes = task.getNotes().iterator();
            while(itr_notes.hasNext()) {
                taskNote += "\t\t\t" + itr_notes.next() + "\t\t\t";
            }
            final TextView taskNotes = new TextView(getActivity());
            taskNotes.setText(taskNote);
            mScrollView.addView(taskNotes);
        }
    }
}
```

fragment_notes_page.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_page_news_rootview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#EDD9CF"
    android:contentDescription="NotesPage"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context="com.a3m.Controllers.Fragments.NotesPageFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_page_notes_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/nav_header_marginLeft">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="171dp"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:text="Notes"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm aware that the IDs in the `.xml` aren't really good, but I'll improve them later...

If someone has an idea or can show me were the answer is, I'll gladly accept this help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ScrollView` and all it's relatives that scroll the content (i.e. `NestedScrollView`) allow only for one child. You cannot add new views directly to `ScrollView` if it already has one child view.

Quote from java doc to `ScrollView` class:

```
/** 
 * A view group that allows the view hierarchy placed within it to be scrolled.
 * Scroll view may have only one direct child placed within it.
 * To add multiple views within the scroll view, make
 * the direct child you add a view group, for example {@link LinearLayout}, and
 * place additional views within that LinearLayout. 
...
 */
```

And if you look inside of the class you will find that it overrides all `addView` methods:

[image: ScrollView overridden addView methods]

To fix the issue what you need to do is to add `id` to your `LinearLayout` and insert new views into it.

I'd recommend changing it all to `RecyclerView` + `Adapter`.

Official tutorials from Google on [how to use RecyclerView and Adapters](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-recyclerview-fundamentals/#0)

Comment: Thank you, it totally worked! I'll see about `RecyclerView` and `Adapter` next time!